# coalesce with filter function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am running this query:

```
SELECT
     SUM(PRICE) FILTER (my filter's parameters)
```

and when there's no record it returns `<null>`

then I tried:

```
SELECT
       COALESCE(SUM(PRICE),0) FILTER (my filter's parameters)
```

But then I get an error `FILTER not valid for coalesce function`

my filter's parameters are time window, like this:

```
FILTER(WHERE date(order_date) >= (cast(current_date as date) - interval '1' day)) as day1
```

How can I replace  `<null> by 0` when there's no record?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should try wrapping the entire `FILTER` expression in `COALESCE`, e.g.

```sql
SELECT
    COALESCE(SUM(PRICE) FILTER (my filter's parameters), 0) AS sum_price
```